# The Derective has different behavior in hierarchical injectors of different @angualr/cli version(9.0.2 & 8.3.14)

Tags: angular

I am learning Hierarchical injectors in Angular doc.

The doc indicates the difference between providers and viewProviders using a `<ng-content>` example.

The link is [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bxpbeagnyxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Finterceptor.directive.ts)

But I am confused about adding some content except for `component` to the `<app-child>`, just like this:

```
<app-child>{{flower.emoji}}{{animal.emoji}}<app-inspector></app-inspector></app-child>
```

the result seems that the content just finds ElementInjector in the parent component, although the `app-child` component has put `FlowerService` in `providers`.

why? it's my first question, maybe a small question.

another question occurred when I tried to add a directive in `app-child`.

I created a new directive and registered `FlowerService` and `AnimalService` in its `providers`.

Just like this:

```
<app-child appInterceptor>...</app-child>
```

The stackblitz link is [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqed8q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Then I couldn't find some rule in the result. I made more experiments with the same code in Angular v9. (the CLI version is v9.0.2.)

The result is different when the code is all the same!

with v9， the result seems that the `providers` of the directive serve as an interceptor between `providers` and `viewProviders` of `app-child`.

but with v8.3.14...v7.0.0 (CLI version), I found things were different.

Why? (sorry for my poor English...)

Comment: Have you checked '**@Input**' directives? You can inject data using @input directives to child components.

Comment: No, I am sorry that I was just making some experiments, and I understand that I can inject data to child component using `@Input`.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question :

```html
<app-child>{{flower.emoji}}{{animal.emoji}}<app-inspector></app-inspector></app-child>
```

You're adding the `flower.emoji` and `animal.emoji` code to the `app.component.html` **file**, so angular uses the service provided in `app.component.ts`. As `app.component.ts` doesn't provide any service and his parent `app.module.ts` doesn't provide any service either, they use the services provided in root : whale and flower.

In other words: if you displaying a variable in the `app.component.ts` **file** he's displaying what was provided to him (whale and flower) he doesn't know what was provided to `app-child` and should never know (otherwise you're creating **coupling** between your components which is bad)

For you second question I don't know what to tell you, fork the stackblitz with your directive and I can try to explain what is happening there

Good luck in your learning !

Comment: Thanks! I get it for my first question.
Here is the forked stackbliz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqed8q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yeah it looks like the directive overrides the providers of its host component, it's interesting but I can imagine that mixing all of that (host + child + directive provider/viewproviders) in a real example can lead to complicated behaviours. A friendly reminder that your code should be easy to comprehend by your coworkers ;) but if everything is named aptly it looks like a great tool to provide different services in different instances of the same child component